# EF Core 3.1 Query Optimization

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I hear every now and then, that EF Core 3.1 is now capable of optimizing grouping and several aggregate functions like sum to execute on database. Why does my C# code sends this heavily unoptimized SQL code to the database server?

```
using var dbContext = new DatabaseContext();
var someTableData = await dbContext.SomeTable
    .GroupBy(x => x.Foobar)
    .Select(x => new { Foobar = x.Key, Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity) })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```

SQL (copied from Entity Framework log):

```
SELECT [...] FROM public."SomeTable"
```

As you can see: The query does not contain any ordering, grouping, summarizing, ...

I solved my problem by creating a view, since the original ef core query increased RAM usage of application by 2GB (in 2 second) since there were a lot of table entries. But my question remains: What did I do wrong? Is it because I am using PostgreSQL (Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL v3.1.0)?

Comment: Is SomeTable perhaps a view?

Comment: It may very well be because you are using Npgsql, as it is not officially maintained by Microsoft, but is a third party [Data Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). And because the data provider is responsible for actually converting a LINQ expression to whatever (PSQL for you), it may be that the Npsql data provider does not support these features (yet). The things you heard may exclusively apply to the MS developed data providers

Comment: You could use prepared statements ([which are supported by Npgsql](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/prepare.html)) to write your SQL Query manually and then execute it, this way you can make sure your SQL Query is a optimized as you want it to be

Comment: Hmm, this indicates client evaluation, hence doesn't seem to be output from EF Core 3.0+. Client evaluation has been retired and you should get runtime exception in case EF Core cannot translate you `GroupBy` query or some part of it. What is the type of `x.Foobar` btw?

Comment: @jarlh SomeTable is definitely a table.

Comment: @MindSwipe Thanks, but I already found a solution for my specific problem by creating a view who is doing the grouping and the other stuff. And the problem might have been a Npsql issue, I think you are right. But I thought maybe I just did a simple mistake.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yeah, that's the reason why I was wondering that no exception was thrown because of client evaulation. `x.Foobar` is an 32-bit Integer

Comment: I would literally not call i optimization. This is basic SQL that EntityFramework has done 10+ years ago. Ef Core started with an absolute bare minimum of functionality and is moving towards being usable.

Answer (score 1):

I popped your query into a quick test harness (see project definition with all nuget package versions below):

```cs
public class SomeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Foobar { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeTable> SomeTables { get; set; }
    public static readonly LoggerFactory DbCommandConsoleLoggerFactory
        = new LoggerFactory(new[] {
            new ConsoleLoggerProvider ((category, level) =>
                category == DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name &&
                level == LogLevel.Trace, true)
        });
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql("Server=...;Port=5432;Database=test;User Id=...;Password=...;")
        //optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=true")
                    .UseLoggerFactory(DbCommandConsoleLoggerFactory)
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var context = new MyDbContext();
        var someTableData = context.SomeTables
                .GroupBy(x => x.Foobar)
                .Select(x => new { Foobar = x.Key, Quantity = x.Sum(y => y.Quantity) })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity)
                .Take(10);
        Console.Write(someTableData);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
/*csproj file contents below:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>ef_core3_playground</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
*/
```

I ended up getting the following SQL for respective providers:

```
--MS SQL
SELECT TOP(@__p_0) [s].[Foobar], SUM([s].[Quantity]) AS [Quantity]
FROM [SomeTables] AS [s]
GROUP BY [s].[Foobar]
ORDER BY SUM([s].[Quantity]) DESC

-- PG SQL
SELECT s."Foobar", SUM(s."Quantity")::INT AS "Quantity"
FROM "SomeTables" AS s
GROUP BY s."Foobar"
ORDER BY SUM(s."Quantity")::INT DESC
LIMIT @__p_0
```

This makes me wonder if it may be your provider/EF specific versions that give you that result? Although looking at the [diff between two npgsql releases](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/compare/v3.1.0...v3.1.1) I can't see anything relaetd to the issue, but I would suggest you try upgrading all EF-related packages to `3.1.1` and repeat your test.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you very much for your investigation!